# On Angular 6 RouterLink with tabs is not loading the components correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-cli

The template of the tabs is simply this :

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar
     class="nav-container">

<a mat-tab-link
   [routerLink]="'/fixedtabroute'"
   routerLinkActive #rla0="routerLinkActive"
   [active]="rla0.isActive">
  Fixed tab
</a>

<a mat-tab-link
   [routerLink]="tab.link"
   routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
   [active]="rla.isActive"
   *ngFor="let tab of tabs"
   (mousedown)="closeTab($event, tab)">
  <mat-icon>{{ tab.icon }}</mat-icon>
  <p>{{ tab.title }}</p>
  <span>&nbsp;{{tab.index}}</span>

  <div class="tab-close">
    <a mat-icon-button (click)="crossClose($event, tab)">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </a>
  </div>
</a>
</nav>
```

I have a service that keep tracks of openned tabs through an array, as you guess the number of tabs is not fix :

```
public tabs: Tab[] = [];
```

of

```
export interface TabInfo<T = any> {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  link: string;
  data?: T;
}
export class Tab<T = any> implements TabInfo<T> {
  public id: string;
  public title: string;
  public link: string;
  public data?: T;
  constructor(info: TabInfo<T>) {
    this.id = info.id;
    this.title = info.title;
    this.link = info.link;
    this.data = info.data;
  }
}
```

To activate/open a new tab my TabService provide this simple method (This method can be called only from the fixed tab) :

```
  public activate(tab: Tab): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(tab.link);
  }
```

The router is :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'auth',
        component: UnauthenticatedContainerComponent,
        data: { excludeLogin: true },
        children: [
          { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: AuthenticatedContainerComponent,
        data: { requireLogin: true },
        children: [
          { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, resolve: { profile: ProfileResolve } },
          {
            path: '',
            component: RequestContainerComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'requests',
                pathMatch: 'full',
              },
              { path: 'requests', component: RequestListComponent },
              { path: 'request/:id/create/:index', component: RequestComponent },
              { path: 'request/:id/results/:index', component: RequestResultListComponent, canActivate: [TabGuard] },
              { path: 'request/:id/edit/:index', component: RequestComponent, canActivate: [TabGuard] },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' },
];
```

The fixed tab is `RequestListComponent` each tab can be of any other child from `RequestContainerComponent`

The `RequestContainerComponent` template (the componant does nothing else):

```
<app-tabs></app-tabs>
<div class="request-container-wrapper">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The issue is when I navigate between openned tabs from the array, the data of each tab stay the same as the data of either 1)The last openned tab I navigatedByUrl to 2)The last tab oppened after going back to the fixed tab. It happens only between tabs with the same url pattern as described in EDIT1.

---

EDIT1 :

I just tested openning multiple tabs that point to the same route but with different ids for example :

```
In tab 1 : /request/5c98c7eb77f998b79d2a53/edit/1
In tab 2 : /request/5c98cb8b77f998b79d2a58/edit/1
In tab 3 : /request/5c98c8fb77f998b79d2a55/results/1
In tab 4 : /request/5c98c8fb77f998b79d2a54/create/1
```

I can navigate with no component loading or data update issue between : edit, results, create. But if I navigate between different edit tabs nothing change I have my issue.

My issue is only between same url pattern, why ?

Comment: Can you share the code for `TabGuard` ?

Comment: I tried to remove the guard just in case, same result. And it happens in the RequestComponent  which is not protected by the guard

Answer (score 0):

> ### Issue

As your explanation, its look like you have shared the `data` in `tab`. You might be using the same reference when you are adding the `tab` into `tabs`.

> ### Fix

Just do deep cloning of `tab` just before you add into `tabs` variable.

Its better to remove the earlier data for the same tab before adding new one.

### Service Class

```
public tabs: Tab[] = []

public addTab(tab: Tab){
   let cloneTab = JSON.parse(JSON.stringif(tab));
   //remove the old matching tab here.
   this.tabs.push(cloneTab);
}
```

Comment: Just to precise, the correct url is loaded and the tab array is managed correctly also. the issue is only in the component the routerlink refers to. It's difficult to explain. I edited my question

Comment: It's not relevant, you can think of each component as a simple nearly empty component that just has some input and select options. but I can share the template of the container, maybe more usefull